# Using a calculated column to return the list name in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

I have a flow that pulls items from many different lists onto a masterlist and it updates daily. I want to use some sort of calculated column to input the name of the list the list item came from. I know I can enter a default input, but I will probably forget to update this every time I make a new list. I can't find a function that seems to do this.

Comment: You can update the item from your flow and add the source list name in the column. Is this possible for you? Can you add screenshot of your flow to the question to understand what actions you are using exactly in the flow.